# Console showing error "TypeError: this.each is not a function" many times while using SELECT tag on template

Tags: vue.js

I'm implementing a form page with Vue.js using Single File Components. 
The functionality is working as intended but on the Javascript console I have this error showing multiple times when using HTML Select elements:

```
@ vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 

TypeError: this.each is not a function
    at HTMLOptionsCollection.collect (prototype.js:251)
    at inserted (vue.runtime.esm.js:7842)
    at Do (vue.runtime.esm.js:6674)
    at l (vue.runtime.esm.js:6613)
    at s (vue.runtime.esm.js:2235)
    at ne (vue.runtime.esm.js:1854)
    at Object.n [as insert] (vue.runtime.esm.js:2175)
    at $ (vue.runtime.esm.js:6340)
    at Or.__patch__ (vue.runtime.esm.js:6559)
    at Or.Ln.t._update (vue.runtime.esm.js:3939)
```

I narrowed it down the the Select elements. Removing them makes the errors disapear.
Searching Google for this error did not provide any relevant information.

This is the relevant section of the  HTML:

```
<select class="fieldcontent" v-model="oldNumber" >
  <option v-for="hn in houseNumbers" :key="hn.oldNumber">{{hn.oldNumber}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

The select options are populated from a "houseNumbers" object (in a Vuex store) in the format:

```
[{
   "oldNumber": "14",
   "newNumber": ""
},{
   "oldNumber": "15",
   "newNumber": ""
},{
  "oldNumber": "17",
  "newNumber": ""
}]
```

I get them on the component via a computed property:

```
computed: {
    ...mapState(['houseNumbers'])
  },
```

The HTML Select is binded to the local data of that component, shown below:

```
data() {
    return {
      newNumber: null,
      oldNumber: null
    }  
  },
```

This error is thrown both when the component renders and also when I click to change the selected option.

Is there anything I can do to fix this console errors?
Is this an know issue?

The Vue code is running alongside an old application with Struts 1.2 and JSPs, and this application is importing a prototype.js version older than 1.7

Comment: Is `houseNumbers` is an array? If you put {{ houseNumbers }} in your template, what's the result?

Comment: Hi ittus. Yes, it's an array. I updated my description to illustrate this. Thank you. I'm using a v-for to iterate on it. Don't think it can be used in the template without a v-for

Comment: how are you getting `houseNumbers` ? your works  fine https://jsfiddle.net/3f1pscw7/

Comment: Hi kcsujeet, I use a computed property and map the Vuex state locally. I edited my description to add this. Thank you.

Comment: And yes, the funtionality works fine, but I have this errors on the javascript console of the browsers that I would prefer to keep clean, without erros

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Vue?

Comment: The stacktrace refers to `prototype.js` line 251. What is that? Assuming you're using Vue 2.6.10 then line 7842 is `el._vOptions = [].map.call(el.options, getValue);`, which suggests that `prototype.js` is mucking around with the standard Array `map` method.

Comment: Hi skirtle. I have indeed vue: ^2.6.10 in my package.json, and I'm deploying this code inside an existing/old application, so there may indeed be a conflict with an older prototype version. I will try to test the new code alone and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Hi again skirtke. Indeed, I tested the Vue app in standalone, by mocking some data, and the error is not there. I also inspected the old "container" app and I see that prototype.js is being included in it, so I think this is like you say prototype messing around with the map object. Thanks. Can you make an answer out of it so I can mark it correct?

Comment: Indeed. Searching for conflicts between prototype and Vue I found this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5139

Comment: I updated the existing prototype.js to 1.7.3 and the error does not show anymore. Thanks Skirtle